# getView Inflater

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-inflate

This may be an elementary question, but I just want to know: When initializing the Inflater inside the getView() method, what's the different between these lines:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, root);
convertView = View.inflate(context, resource, root);
```

Follow-up question: Which is best to use in initializing the Inflater? Thanks for any response.

Comment: see this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Answer (score 1):

The `View#inflate()` method will take care of retrieving the `LayoutInflater` from the `Context` for you, while the former method will use an inflater method you fetched.

If you have to inflate a view just once, you can use the `View#inflate()` method as it is more convenient.

If you are inflating the views in an adapter, however, since you have to repeatedly inflate views, it would be better to get the `LayoutInflater` object just once(In the constructor of your adapter, pass the `Activity` context or the `LayoutInflater` object) and reuse that same inflater object in your `getView()`.